# how do I remove additional anchor tag in a bootstrapped WordPress dropdown menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Code used in `functions.php` to create WordPress `[Dropdown enabled]` Twitter Bootstrap

### Menu: http://pastebin.com/HCxCcBmG

### Code used in `header.php`: http://pastebin.com/7eTHTjij

Here's what gets generated for the dropdown menu code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
  <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/site-design/">site design</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/app-design/">app design</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/windows/">windows</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/mac/">mac</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I remove the additional anchor tag/link genereated in the first dropdown menu link? Like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
  <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/site-design/">site design</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/app-design/">app design</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/windows/">windows</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32">
    <a href="http://localhost/site/projects/mac/">mac</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @ChapDaddy65 ... I think your walker was not properly extended, you see in line `33` there is already a class being added when it has children... why didn't you use that instead of what you did with line `50`?

Comment: the code in the pastebin links was not written by me, I found them as a gist. I'll try to find the source. I'll look at those lines...

Comment: Sorry, i'm not well versed in what looks like advanced PHP to me...so I'm not sure what to do exactly. I do understand what your driving at with the redundancy, but what do I need to remove and/or replace?